# how to add bulk pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bulk

So I have one page template ready . I want to make 2000 copies of that page . Sample of page you will see here

```
hostvento.com/wordpress-hosting.php
```

I want to create page for each script like joomla hosting magento hosting etc.

Also I want to replace script name in page. What is the best way to doing this ?

I have list.txt file in which I have added all the page names.

any plugin or shell script will work in this case.

Comment: I want to create more pages like wordpress hosting and page names I have saved in list.txt. . in that i have name joomla-hosting.php magento-hosting.php opencart-hosting.php

Comment: So loop over your page names, and call wp_insert_post to create new pages ...?

Comment: thanks I will try that now

Answer (score 1):

Just a rough sketch but something like this:

```
$post = get_post( YOUR_BASE_POST_ID )

$file = fopen( YOUR_TXT_FILE_PATH, "r");

while( ( $line = fgets( $file ) ) !== false ):

    $handler = $post;
    $handler['ID'] = 0;
    $handler['post_title'] = $line;

    wp_insert_post( $handler );

endwhile;

fclose( $file );
```

You probably have to adjust some other fields or take care of postmeta ... but you get the idea ;)